# Cannot download TFS 2013 build process template, and build fails to initialize

Tags: tfs

I have recently installed TFS 2013 on a single server (10 GB, 8 core XEON server). The installation also includes VS 2013 (pro). I tried to create a build definition and run the build, but the build immediately fails (see log below).

I tried to download the template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml), but after what I think is a 90 second timeout I get a "One or more errors have occurred" message. When I open my local folder, the file has a size of 0 bytes.

Any idea what might be the cause?

### Update

The ***downloading*** issue might be limited to the Visual Studio (2013 pro) instance that was installed on the TFS server. Downloading it on a different machine worked.

### Build error log:

TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \TeamProject\Continuous-Build: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: An error occurred while sending the request. (type HttpRequestException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.d_*0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.d*_2.MoveNext()

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. (type WebException)Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (type IOException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (type SocketException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: Didn't work for me; nor did another machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was but clearing the cache in VS' appdata folder solved the problem.

For future reference, you can clear the cache by going into ***{User Profile Folder}***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

And delete its contents. Restart Visual Studio.

FYI - the 5.0 is the version of TFS (v5.0 is 2013). Your actual cache folder will depend on the version of TFS you're connecting to (4.0 is 2012, 3.0 is 2010, 2.0 is 2008, and 1.0 is 2005).

Comment: 'fraid this didn't work for me either. When I try download I get a "Visual studio is busy" speech bubble from the task bar, it hangs for about 30 seconds then download an empty file for the xaml.

Comment: Rob, I get the same error. Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Same issue. Any solutions?  I have brand new VS2013 Update 5 install this is happening on.